# Cannot add users to Google Console Project

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-console-developer

I am attempting to add a project owner within Google Developer Console under Permissions. The original project was created with a domain user (Google Apps for Work) and I can add other domain users but cannot add external users (other gmail or different Google Apps domain user).

I receive a 504 error in the Console logs and a message saying "The server has timed out while trying to process your request."

Has anyone seen or resolved this issue? Or perhaps know of a way to contact Google support regarding this?

**UPDATE:**

I realized that the this happens for two of our projects and both projects have a prefix on the project ID: carrotcreates.com:xxxxxxxx

I am not sure if this is linked but carrotcreates.com is the primary domain for our Google Apps account.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find answer?

Comment: Sadly not. Google was no help.